# Wifi turns off automatically in Ubuntu 16.04 if speed goes above 150 Mbps

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I have 5G internet connection. Speed is always between 200 - 300 Mbps. When I am downloading something and download speed goes above 150 Mbps, WiFi turn off. It doesn't even show available WiFis. Rebooting the system doesn't help. I have to shut down the system and start again. I researched and tried below solutions but unfortunately none worked.

1. Restart network manager.
2. Disable power management
3. Disable 11n
4. Uninstalled network-manager and installed WICD network manager
5. Reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04

My system:
Lenovo Thinkpad P52.
Wireless Card: Intel Wireless AC 9560<

Anybody faced same issue and have solution? I will really appreciate the help as I am trying to resolve this issue for last 1 month and it's driving me crazy.

Thanks

---

[Solved]

Updated the kernel to 5.1.3 using Ukuu Kernel Update Utility. It's been 2 days now since laptop is up and running and WiFi is not turned off. Noticed other things as well after updating the kernel. WiFi Signal is always 100% now. Earlier it was always between 80 - 90 percent. Also, boot time has reduced significantly.

Comment: Have you tried a new wireless driver? New Intel drivers for ThinkPads out this year for some of our machines.  Also update BIOS on this machine.

Comment: @John Yes, I tried from this one - https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html. But result is same. Do you think updating BIOS can resolve this issue? Any alternate solution that I can possibly try?

Comment: I am not sure that BIOS will fix the issue but new ThinkPad BIOS updates were out this year as well. I keep my ThinkPad drivers updated.

Comment: I think I should give it a try. Do you also have same Ubuntu version?

Comment: No but driver updates on my computer appear to help in general.

Comment: I checked just now. No new updated drivers. The one that I have installed is the latest one. However, I will do BIOS update tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

Updated the kernel to 5.1.3 using Ukuu Kernel Update Utility. It's been 2 days now since laptop is up and running and WiFi is not turned off. Noticed other things as well after updating the kernel. WiFi Signal is always 100% now. Earlier it was always between 80 - 90 percent. Also, boot time has reduced significantly.